# wordpress help... integrating existing PHP code to work side-by-side

Tags: php, wordpress

I know very little of WP aside form it being a CMS geared towards (or started from) blogging, but may people have found the product capable of functioning as their sites CMS.

I was recently asked to write a PHP app to signup, (with email confirm and email notification to admin), login to make and manage orders. - so a user can register and get an email confirmation... once they are approved, they can log in, and place an order. and manage their information. There is also an admin section to manage the users and requests... ALL very straight ahead.

So I write it - and test it and everything is fine... Until the client tells me that it's going to be part of a WP site.

Problem, the client ONLY knows HTML, NOT PHP... I don't know WP.

When I upload a directory to the root - and try to run the app, I get redirect to /$url .. and a page not found displaying in the WP theme.

I have a feeling it has to do with the AUTH module I'm using... but there is a huge BIG PICTURE issue I need to conquer - how to integrate an existing PHP app into a WP site...

Q: how do I reference and use the WP emailing system?

thx - I know it's a broad question. but if someone can point me into a direction...
I have read the post regarding templates in WP and setting up a template with PHP code so it's executed... but it seems 'wrong' to have to create a template for each php page.

Comment: Worpress can be extended via [Plugins](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugins). Since there are literally thousands of 3rd party developments for Wordpress, maybe you'll be lucky enough to find one that already does what you've been hired to do. If not, I'd recommend you to start reading Wordpress' official documentation about [Writing a Plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin).

Answer (score 0):

What your app is about ? If you got only the Auth module already coded you should only import user and password because WP does this out-of-the-box.

Wordpress can be twist up for your need but you need to do it in the WP way :).

If you want to add some functions to it check out the plugin library on [wordpress.org](https://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/). If you know wordpress and no plugin match your needs then the best way to go is writing your own plugin : https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin

Or maybe just add your custom functions into functions.php, see https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Functions_File

For pages, you basically have to type of it in WP : articles - i.e. blog posts - and the static pages. You can add some custom one check https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types

I know this answer is more a bunch of links but if you don't nothing about WP you should first learn how it works before try to hack it.

Hope it helps !